# How do i create dynamic Checkbox in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox

I need to create dynamic checkbox using jQuery.
How do i do that?
Any code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: How more dynamic can a checkbox be? you might need to be a little more specific...

Answer (score 17):

```
$('#containerId').append('<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />');
```

where `containerId` is the id of the DOM element you want to add the checkbox to.

Or alternative syntax...

```
$('#containerId')
    .append(
       $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
           id:    'myCheckbox',
           name:  'myCheckbox',
           value: 'myValue',
           type:  'checkbox'
       })
    );
```

Comment: I really like the literal option for labels but how can I use variables to fill out the tag? For example, var name = name;  $('#containerId').append('<label>name</label>');